# 2 mapped structs with an address array - push not working

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct

Can someone help me understand why the function `add` in the contract **one** is not working and in the contract **two** is?

Both are mined and are inserted into the blockchain.

Thanks.

**Not working contract**

```
contract one {
    struct A {
        address[] count;
    }
    struct B {
        uint8[] count;
    }

    mapping (address => A) a;
    mapping (address => B) b;

    function add(address c, uint8 g) {
        a[msg.sender].count.push(c);
        b[msg.sender].count.push(g);
    }
}
```

**Working contract**

```
contract two {
    struct A {
        address[] count;
    }

    mapping (address => A) a;

    function add(address c) {
        a[msg.sender].count.push(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error? Did you try to see what was in the struct? I've been having funny issues with address arrays over/underflowing other parameter values.

Comment: It returns "0x" for address and 0 for uint8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

Works perfectly. I do get the ["0x", 0] message if I call the functions `get1()` and `get2()` immediately after the I send the `add(...)` transaction. But after waiting a while more, the `get1()` and `get2()` functions return the expected values.

---

## Details

## Modification To Your Code

I've modified your code to add some functions to view the inserted data:

```
contract TwoStructs {
    struct A {
        address[] count;
    }
    struct B {
        uint8[] count;
    }

    mapping (address => A) a;
    mapping (address => B) b;

    function add(address c, uint8 g) {
        a[msg.sender].count.push(c);
        b[msg.sender].count.push(g);
    }

    function get1(address sender) constant returns (address, uint8) {
        return (a[sender].count[0], b[sender].count[0]);
    }

    function get2() constant returns (address, uint8) {
        return (a[msg.sender].count[0], b[msg.sender].count[0]);
    }

    function getMsgSender() constant returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

### Running `geth`

I'm running the Dev blockchain using the following parameters:

```
geth --datadir /home/user/DevData --dev --nodiscover \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --port 30301 --maxpeers 0  \
  --verbosity 3 --rpc console
```

### Flattened Your Code And Assigned To A Variable

You can use a service like [Line Break Removal Tool](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) to strip out your line breaks, or see [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/how-to-load-solidity-source-file-into-geth) for some alternatives.

I flattened your code, assigned it to a variable and pasted it into `geth`:

```
> var twoStructsSource='contract TwoStructs { struct A { address[] count; } struct B { uint8[] count; } mapping (address => A) a; mapping (address => B) b; function add(address c, uint8 g) { a[msg.sender].count.push(c); b[msg.sender].count.push(g); } function get1(address sender) constant returns (address, uint8) { return (a[sender].count[0], b[sender].count[0]); } function get2() constant returns (address, uint8) { return (a[msg.sender].count[0], b[msg.sender].count[0]); } function getMsgSender() constant returns (address) { return msg.sender; }}'
```

### Compiled Your Code

I compiled your code using the following command:

```
> var twoStructsCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(twoStructsSource);
```

### Inserted Your Code Into The Blockchain

I used the following commands to insert your code into the blockchain:

```
> var twoStructsContract = web3.eth.contract(twoStructsCompiled.TwoStructs.info.abiDefinition);
> var twoStructs = twoStructsContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: twoStructsCompiled.TwoStructs.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
```

And waited for the following message:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0xe924f5c2240bfb2a78d46a8ebfb2bc149cfeeff0
```

## Sent Transaction To Add Data

I inserted some sample data into the blockchain using the following command:

```
> twoStructs.add(eth.accounts[0], 123, {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: twoStructsCompiled.TwoStructs.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
```

And waited for the transaction to be mined.

```
"0xe4966cb845f5e929eb554c772e9982a2e1c5f3da3190a13cca5994a4f11f4143"
```

## Check Data Inserted

If I immediately run `twoStructs.get1(eth.accounts[0])`, I get the following results:

```
> twoStructs.get1(eth.accounts[0])
...
PC 00000104: JUMPI GAS: 49977033 COST: 10 ERROR: invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2
...
["0x", 0]
```

If I want a few more seconds:

```
> twoStructs.get1(eth.accounts[0])
["0xa485ab3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed", 123]

> twoStructs.get2()
["0xa485ab3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed", 123]

> twoStructs.getMsgSender()
"0xa485ab3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed"
```

as expected. If you get the `["0x", 0]`, wait for some time then try again.

Comment: Hi. I'm tested work instructions and it work fine.using the following intructions to