# Returning a struct and reading via Web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, struct

I am storing data in my contract using a mapping of structs.

For examples sake, say I'm storing employee info (name/address/salary), mapped by their employee ID.

Via a web front-end, I'd like to be able to specify an employee ID, and call a function in my contract (using Web3.JS) that returns the employee info.

How can I access the data if a struct is returned. Is that possible?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Summary

Return the fields of the struct as separate return variables.

**Edit:** As of 2021, it's possible to return the struct directly. See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/101745/63911).

---

## Example

I'm running this code in my local dev blockchain using the following command:

```
geth --datadir ~/devdata --dev --nodiscover \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --port 30301      \
  --maxpeers 0 --verbosity 3 --rpc console
```

Your web frontend should be able to send transactions to insert the users, and call the functions to get the number of users and and the user info.

### Sample Contract

```
contract SalaryInfo {
    struct User {
        uint salaryId;
        string name;
        string userAddress;
        uint salary;
    }
    User[] public users;

    function addUser(uint _salaryId, string _name, string _userAddress, uint _salary) public returns(uint) {
        users.length++;
        users[users.length-1].salaryId = _salaryId;
        users[users.length-1].name = _name;
        users[users.length-1].userAddress = _userAddress;
        users[users.length-1].salary = _salary;
        return users.length;
    }

    function getUsersCount() public constant returns(uint) {
        return users.length;
    }

    function getUser(uint index) public constant returns(uint, string, string, uint) {
        return (users[index].salaryId, users[index].name, users[index].userAddress, users[index].salary);
    }
}
```

### Flatten The Source Code

I use the `stripCrLf` method (from [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/how-to-load-solidity-source-file-into-geth/2610#2610)) to transform the formatted source into a single line that can be inserted within the `geth` console. Alternatively,  search for a web page that will strip your line breaks from your code. Then assign your code to a JavaScript variable:

```
> var salaryInfoSource='contract SalaryInfo { struct User { uint salaryId; string name; string userAddress; uint salary; } User[] public users; function addUser(uint _salaryId, string _name, string _userAddress, uint _salary) public returns(uint) { users.length++; users[users.length-1].salaryId = _salaryId; users[users.length-1].name = _name; users[users.length-1].userAddress = _userAddress; users[users.length-1].salary = _salary; return users.length; } function getUsersCount() public constant returns(uint) { return users.length; } function getUser(uint index) public constant returns(uint, string, string, uint) { return (users[index].salaryId, users[index].name, users[index].userAddress, users[index].salary); }}'
```

### Insert Contract Into The Blockchain

The compile the code:

```
> var salaryInfoCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(salaryInfoSource);
```

Load the code into the blockchain:

```
> var salaryInfoContract = web3.eth.contract(salaryInfoCompiled.SalaryInfo.info.abiDefinition);
> var salaryInfo = salaryInfoContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: salaryInfoCompiled.SalaryInfo.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Wait for the following message to indicate that the contract has been mined:

```
I0505 09:12:15.712867   27030 xeth.go:1026] Tx(0x7747500b881c8da44efbc3b5d1c2c762f1cd52d2dd74050edbfed10e51a29d8a) created: 0x0bb1d7a6b31f7a7e23e6d902bac0eb5f9c721c54
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x7747500b881c8da44efbc3b5d1c2c762f1cd52d2dd74050edbfed10e51a29d8a waiting to be mined...
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x0bb1d7a6b31f7a7e23e6d902bac0eb5f9c721c54
[object Object]
```

### Insert Users

And here we are adding 2 users to the contract:

```
> salaryInfo.addUser(123, "User 123", "123 drive way, the uncentralised kingdom", 100, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: salaryInfoCompiled.SalaryInfo.code, gas: 500000});
"0x7c22797d6b7717beb398a65159b1009fba3bbc9e4917ee1584bed60ea74eac11"
> salaryInfo.addUser(234, "User 234", "234 drive way, the uncentralised kingdom", 200, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: salaryInfoCompiled.SalaryInfo.code, gas: 500000});
"0xed197c9a6fbc70c19cc95bcdc6943e38736c080052e9e1a4f7562216d6de4c78"
```

### Retrieve Data

Let's get the number of users:

```
> var numberOfUsers = salaryInfo.getUsersCount();
undefined
> numberOfUsers
2
```

Let's get the information for the first user:

```
> salaryInfo.getUser(0)
[123, "User 123", "123 drive way, the uncentralised kingdom", 100]
```

And the second user:

```
> var user2 = salaryInfo.getUser(1);
undefined

> user2
[234, "User 234", "234 drive way, the uncentralised kingdom", 200]
```

Comment: Wow! This is incredibly helpful.

Thank you so much for your in-depth answer. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I get a BigNumber not a Base 16 number... how can I return string attributes with your kind of solution?? (I'm using web3 0.16)

Comment: @BokkyPooBah same issue.  Getting  same big nunber issue.  Any help on this?

Answer (score 11):

Starting from solidity 0.8.0 you can return a struct directly. Here is a simple example contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract Example {
    struct Store {
        string id;         
        uint time;         
    }
 
    mapping (address => Store) public purchases;

    function set(string memory _id, uint _time) public returns(bool) {
        purchases[msg.sender].id = _id;
        purchases[msg.sender].time = _time;
        return true;
    }

    function get() public view returns(Store memory) {
        return purchases[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

If you must use any solidity version <0.8.0, then you need to add this for the code above to work:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example from my work:

```
function getChannel(bytes32 channelId) returns(
    address addr0,
    address addr1,
    uint8 phase,
    uint challengePeriod,
    uint closingBlock,
    bytes state,
    uint sequenceNumber,
    bytes evidence0,
    bytes evidence1
) {
    addr0 = channels[channelId].addr0;
    addr1 = channels[channelId].addr1;
    phase = channels[channelId].phase;
    challengePeriod = channels[channelId].challengePeriod;
    closingBlock = channels[channelId].closingBlock;
    state = channels[channelId].state;
    sequenceNumber = channels[channelId].sequenceNumber;
    evidence0 = channels[channelId].evidence0;
    evidence1 = channels[channelId].evidence1;
}
```

This returns

```
[ 
    '0xe7d3b0123a4f0294e06d212876ade6277b47f473',
    '0x3e4280efa3dd3014ca26022ac7dfe8e6c3070c67',
    { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
    { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
    { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
    '0x2222',
    { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
    '0x',
    '0x' 
]
```

Not the most readable, but that's life!

Comment: You never wrote a return statement? Does it return automatically since its the same variable names?

Answer (score 5):

You can only return a struct from a function for internal calls in a contract.

One possible approach would be to return the content of the struct in an array.

Comment: But that might work only if all the members of the struct are of the same type, no ? From the salary example above, one can not return "string" username and "uint" salary in the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` you can return a struct and read it via web3js.

Here is a simple example contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
    
contract Example {

    struct Store {
        string id;         
        uint time;         
    }
 
    mapping (address => Store) public purchases;

    function set(string memory _id, uint _time) public returns(bool) {
        purchases[msg.sender].id = _id;
        purchases[msg.sender].time = _time;
        return true;
    }

    function get() public view returns(Store memory) {
        return purchases[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

JavaScript code to read the struct:

```js
Example.methods.get().call({from: userAddress})
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result[0]);
  console.log(result[1]);
});
```

Comment: This is a good example that I am following. Wondering if the mapping here should be  mapping (address => Store) public purchases; rather than string=> Store given later purchases[msg.sender] is being used?

Comment: Yes it should be address => store you are right