# How can I return struct when function is called?

Tags: solidity, struct, selfdestruct

I'd like to return struct type `User`. However, when I tried the following `getUser` function, it returns an error. Is there any way that struct data would be returned from a function?

**Contract**

```
struct User{
    uint256 user_id;
    bytes32 name;
    bytes32 address;
    bytes32 birth_day;
}
mapping (uint256 => User) public users;

function getUser(uint256 user_id) constant returns (User) {
        return users[user_id];
}
```

**Error**

> client/lib/contracts/User.sol: Solidity errors: :125:58: Error: Expected type name
>   
> function getUser(uint256 user_id) constant returns (struct User) {

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can not return a `struct` because Solidity implements them only as a loose bag of variables, they are not real objects.

You can use a solution from this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3614/264

### Update

Since `0.4.17` you can use `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` to return structs. Of course, until the `experimental` keyword is removed, it's not safe to use it in production apps.

Comment: The answer is a year old. Are there any updates? Or we still can not return struct array from solidity function.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I updated the answer.

Comment: @PaulBerg again one year from now ;) any update?

Comment: @Senju It's safe to use it in Production, it's been 3 years after all

Answer (score 11):

### [UPDATE] Solidity Compiler version >= 0.8.0

If you want to retrieve a specific struct (in this case User's struct) from a mapping, you can do it without `ABIEncoderV2`.
You can see this smart contract code, after this line, to do this operation:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract RetrieveStruct {

    struct User{
        uint256 _user_id;
        bytes32 _name;
        bytes32 _address;
        bytes32 _birth_day;
    }
    mapping (uint256 => User) public users;

    function setUser(uint _idUser) public {
        users[_idUser]._user_id = 0;
        users[_idUser]._name = 0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
        users[_idUser]._address = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB870000000000000000000000000000000000;
        users[_idUser]._birth_day = 0xf711600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    }

    function getUser(uint256 user_id) external view returns (User memory) {
        return users[user_id];
    }

}
```

Solidity allows you to returns the struct linking it to a keywords: memory or calldata, that means the data area where variables must store.

**NOTE:** If you change the visibility about a specific variable to public, Solidity generate automatically a getter function and you can avoid to implement getter() functions.

Comment: NOTE: This doesn't work for nested `struct` variables. You get an error: `TypeError: Types containing (nested) mappings can only be parameters or return variables of internal or library functions.`

Answer (score 5):

Passing structs is available in 0.4.17 with **pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2**. See https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/40

Answer (score 4):

This will only work when the struct is passed around within the contract via the use of internal function calls. Even using ABIEncoderV2, when attempting to return a struct via a public or external function will give the following error:
`error: Failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple`

Answer (score 3):

```
struct User{
    uint256 user_id;
    bytes32 name;
    bytes32 address;
    bytes32 birth_day;
}
mapping (uint256 => User) public users;

function getUser(uint256 user_id) constant returns (uint) {
return users[user_id].user_id;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work straight forward but here is the workaround. https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-returning-structs-from-public-functions-e78e48efb378

Answer (score 1):

Solidity automatically adds a getter to public mappings and returns a tuple, so there is no need for a function like  `getUser(uint256 user_id)`.

Check out [solidity documentation for returning multiple values](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/control-structures.html#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

A solution I discovered to return the array as a string,

```
struct User{
   uint256 user_id;
   bytes32 name;
   bytes32 address;
   bytes32 birth_day;
}
mapping (uint256 => User) public users;
```

now create a function,

```
function getUsers() public view returns(string memory) {
    string memory output="";
    for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        output = string(abi.encodedPack(output,"[", users[i].user_id, ",", users[i].name, ",", users[i].address, ",", users[i].birth_day, "]"));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: be careful with the type error !  `abi.encodePack` ==> `abi.encodePacked`

Answer (score 1):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract UserMgnt{
   struct User{
        uint256 user_id;
        bytes32 name;
        bytes32 address;
        bytes32 birth_day;
    }
    mapping (uint256 => User) public users;
    
    function getUser(uint256 user_id) constant returns (User memory) {
            return users[user_id];
    }
}
```

This worked for me. I had to add `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` in the top of my solidity file and I had to make sure to add the keyword `memory` to returned type User `function getUser(uint256 user_id) constant returns (User memory) {...}`.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with the new versions of solidity you can return a struct also by using memory keyword after writing struct name in return type.

Example:

```js
    function ___(___) ____ ___ ___ returns(struct_name memory){
         _________;
         return structInstance;
    }
```