# Can't retrieve public array members with web3

Tags: contract-development, web3js, struct

I'm building a web interface for my dapp, but can't seem to retrieve individual `struct` items from a public array.

I'm trying to retrieve a `Proposal` struct from the `proposals()` public function in my contract (I have a `Proposal[] public proposals;` array).

So the user enters a particular `proposalID` and they should be returned the `Proposal` struct. The method works fine on Remix.

However, I'm getting this alert:

`error BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number`

I've verified the ABI is correct when I initialize my JS myContract object.

What's causing this error? Here's the code that's resulting in an error:

```
            myContract.proposals(propID, function(error, result) {
                if(!error) {
                    alert("Result: " + result);
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem: " + error);
                }
            });
```

All the other functions work (ie. `myContract.owner` etc).

Comment: Looks like one can't return a struct for anything other than `internal` use...need to make an accessor method that returns the relevant parts.

Comment: You got it right. You can't return a public struct (at least not now, maybe in future).

Comment: Similar question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/how-can-i-return-struct-when-function-is-called

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one can't return a struct for anything other than `internal` use...

Instead, make an accessor method that returns the relevant parts of the struct.