# Getting 'invalid opcode' error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, invalid-opcode

First of all, sorry for the code in Portuguese, this was a choice of the team and I had no saying on that.

I'm writing a Billet Manager, the code is as follows:

```
contract GerenciadorBoletos {

     struct Boleto {
         uint codigoBarra;
         uint codigoBarraDigitavel;
         uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario;
         uint cpfOuCnpjPagador;
         uint valorOriginal;
         uint dataVencimento;
     }

     mapping(uint => Boleto) registroBoletos;

     function inserirBoleto(
         uint codigoBarra,
         uint codigoBarraDigitavel,
         uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario,
         uint cpfOuCnpjPagador,
         uint valorOriginal,
         uint dataVencimento
     ) {
         Boleto memory b = Boleto(
             codigoBarra,
             codigoBarraDigitavel,
             cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario,
             cpfOuCnpjPagador,
             valorOriginal,
             dataVencimento
         );

         // I need to do some validations before store it, but there is no code yet

         registroBoletos[b.codigoBarra] = b;
     }
}
```

I'm testing it with TestRPC and Mocha:

```
 describe('1. Inserção', function(){
     it('Deve ter inserido um boleto com os dados válidos com sucesso', function(done){
         var boletoParaInserir = gerarBoletoValido();
         console.log(boletoParaInserir);

         gerenciadorBoleto.inserirBoleto.sendTransaction(
             9872387128, 987128382, 91289312, 81273818, 50, Date.now() + 3*24*3600,
             {
                 from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
                 gas: 3000000,
             },
             function(e, result) {
                 expect(e).to.not.exist;

                 expect(result).to.exist;
                 result.should.be.above(0);
             }
         );
     });
 });
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught AssertionError: expected [Error: Error: VM Exception while 
>     executing transaction: invalid opcode
> ```

### Edit

This seems to be an issue with TestRPC.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/84) on github.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

There is no error when the code is inserted into `geth` and run.

Can you try inserting your code into `geth` and see if you still the geth "invalid opcode" error.

From the OPs response in the comment, the "invalid opcode" issue is caused by the timing of the test case.

---

## Details

### Modified Your Code

I've modified your code slightly, changing the `//` comment into `/* ... */` and added a public to your mapping structure:

```
contract GerenciadorBoletos {

    struct Boleto {
        uint codigoBarra;
        uint codigoBarraDigitavel;
        uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario;
        uint cpfOuCnpjPagador;
        uint valorOriginal;
        uint dataVencimento;
    }

    mapping(uint => Boleto) public registroBoletos;

    function inserirBoleto(
        uint codigoBarra,
        uint codigoBarraDigitavel,
        uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario,
        uint cpfOuCnpjPagador,
        uint valorOriginal,
        uint dataVencimento
    ) {
        Boleto memory b = Boleto(
            codigoBarra,
            codigoBarraDigitavel,
            cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario,
            cpfOuCnpjPagador,
            valorOriginal,
            dataVencimento
        );

        /* I need to do some validations before store it, but there is no code yet */

        registroBoletos[b.codigoBarra] = b;
    }
}
```

### Running `geth`

I'm running the Dev blockchain using the following parameters:

```
geth --datadir /home/user/DevData --dev --nodiscover \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --port 30301 --maxpeers 0  \
  --verbosity 3 --rpc console
```

### Flattened Your Code And Assigned To A Variable

You can use a service like [Line Break Removal Tool](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) to strip out your line breaks, or see [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/how-to-load-solidity-source-file-into-geth) for some alternatives.

I flattened your code, assigned it to a variable and pasted it into `geth`:

```
> var gerenciadorBoletosSource='contract GerenciadorBoletos { struct Boleto { uint codigoBarra; uint codigoBarraDigitavel; uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario; uint cpfOuCnpjPagador; uint valorOriginal; uint dataVencimento; } mapping(uint => Boleto) public registroBoletos; function inserirBoleto( uint codigoBarra, uint codigoBarraDigitavel, uint cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario, uint cpfOuCnpjPagador, uint valorOriginal, uint dataVencimento ) { Boleto memory b = Boleto( codigoBarra, codigoBarraDigitavel, cpfOuCnpjBeneficiario, cpfOuCnpjPagador, valorOriginal, dataVencimento ); /* I need to do some validations before store it, but there is no code yet */ registroBoletos[b.codigoBarra] = b; }}'
```

### Compiled Your Code

I compiled your code using the following command:

```
> var gerenciadorBoletosCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(gerenciadorBoletosSource);
```

### Inserted Your Code Into The Blockchain

I used the following commands to insert your code into the blockchain:

```
var gerenciadorBoletosContract = web3.eth.contract(gerenciadorBoletosCompiled.GerenciadorBoletos.info.abiDefinition);
var gerenciadorBoletos = gerenciadorBoletosContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: gerenciadorBoletosCompiled.GerenciadorBoletos.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
```

And waited for the following message:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0x9e550b10e770b050d6ec9af80c5fdb6540089803
```

## Sent Transaction To Add Data

I copied the main part of your `sendTransaction` to insert your sample data into the blockchain:

```
> gerenciadorBoletos.inserirBoleto.sendTransaction(
    9872387128, 987128382, 91289312, 81273818, 50, Date.now() + 3*24*3600,
    {
      from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
      gas: 3000000,
    },
    function(e, result) {
      expect(e).to.not.exist;
      expect(result).to.exist;
      result.should.be.above(0);
    }
  );
```

And waited for the transaction to be mined.

### Inspecting Data After Data Inserted

```
> gerenciadorBoletos.registroBoletos(9872387128)
[9872387128, 987128382, 91289312, 81273818, 50, 1462459836202]
```

### No Invalid Opcode

I double checked my `geth` messages and I did not get the "invalid opcode" message.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just figured out that it's a problem with TestRPC, because if I run the tests directly on ethereum, it works perfectly. The problem is that this takes time and I need it to be fast in order to create a comprehensive test suite.

Comment: I confirm that running on an actual node gives me no error. However, the it seems like the data is not being stored, since I try to obtain it after inserting and get a zero-value struct.

Comment: see the end of my answer. data is stored. just have to use the key to the mapping.

Comment: I'm doing that, but is returning me an empty struct

Comment: Note that I have made the mapping public. Try copying and pasting the code from my answer as I did get it to work.

Comment: I've done that! But this is a different issue. I'm opening a new question.

Comment: [New question here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/contract-storage-not-being-updated-after-sendtransaction)