# Testing contract interactions with Truffle

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation

I have 2 contracts, User and Registry, interacting and I want to test their interactions with Truffle. Currently my test(s) for User are

```
contract('User', function(accounts) {
  // many tests here which only depend on User contract
})
```

I now want to test the interaction between the user contract and a registry contract. The relevant parts of each are

User.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "./Registry.sol";

contract User { 
    address owner;
    address reg;
    bool verified;
    Registry registry = Registry(reg);

    // Register in the system
    function register(bytes32 _id)
        onlyOwner
    {
        registry.register(_id);
    }
    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id)
        onlyOwner
    {
        registry.getContractAddress(_id);
    }
    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id)
        onlyOwner
    {
        registry.getPublicAddress(_id);
    }
    function verify()
        onlyReg
    {
        verified = true;
    }
}
```

Registry.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "./User.sol";

contract Registry {
    mapping(bytes32 => address) ID;
    mapping(address => address) Contract;

    function register(bytes32 _id) {
        ID[_id] = tx.origin;
        Contract[tx.origin] = msg.sender;
    }

    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) {
        return (ID[_id]);
    }

    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) { 
        return Contract[ID[_id]];
    }   

    function verify() {
        User requester = User(msg.sender);
        requester.verify();
    }
}
```

How can I write a test in which Registry is deployed so I can then test `register()`, `getContractAddress()`, etc?

I checked out the [docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests) but didn't find examples there.

EDIT: Just to complement to answer that was given

I added this

```
contract('User', function(accounts) {
  var user 
  var registry // new part based on your answer
  Registry.new().then((inst) => {
    registry = inst;
  })

  // Check contract was deployed
  it("Should retrieve deployed contract", function(done) {
      // test
  })
```

It works and further down I have a test to set/get reg address which works fine (which means by the time I call a method on the contract, the address is already there). The problem is in this test

```
// Should not find user
  it("Should not find user", function(done) {
    patient.getPublicAddress(web3.fromAscii("123456789"), {from:accounts[0], to:patient.address})
    .then(function(res) {
      assert.equal(res, 0);
      done()
    }, function(error) {
        // Force an error if callback fails.
        console.error(error)
        assert.equal(true, false)
        done()
      })
  })
```

it returns `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`. There is this question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/getting-invalid-opcode-error) but I didn't get how to make it work from there (though I did make the mappings public in Registry).

Answer (score 1):

You should first deploy Registry contract and then User.

You can add a constructor to the User contract to instantiate `reg` with the address of the Registry contract.

Also by making your mapping globals `public`, the solidity compiler will automatically create getter functions, which will be necessary for testing.

The constructor for User would look like this:

```
function User(address _registry) {
    reg = _registry;
}
```

In a js file for your truffle test, you can get started by writing a promise chain to hit your contracts. 
(Assuming you have compiled and written migrations for the contracts)

```
const Registry = artifacts.require('./Registry.sol')
const User = artifacts.require('./User.sol')

let registry
let user
let id = '0x...' // bytes 32 id

Registry.new().then((inst) => {
    registry = inst
    return User.new(registry.address)
}).then((inst) => {
    user = inst
    return user.register.call(id)
}).then((res) => {
    return registry.ID.call(id)
}).then((res) => {
    assert.equal(user.address, res)
})
```

Comment: I actually accepted it too fast. It partially worked for me. The contract was deployed and I got back the address fine. But when I try to test methods which depend on it I get the error `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`. I've edited the question to include that.

Comment: @Sean Pollock!!! what up dude?!?!