# Debugging registering in a mapping

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I have this contract called Registry

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Registry {
    mapping(bytes32 => address) public ID;
    mapping(address => address) public Contract;

    function register(bytes32 _id) {
        ID[_id] = tx.origin;
        Contract[tx.origin] = msg.sender;
    }

    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) {
        return (ID[_id]);
    }

    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) { 
        return Contract[ID[_id]];
    } 
}
```

and another called User

```
contract User { 
    address owner;
    address reg;
    Registry registry = Registry(reg);
    // Register in the system
    function register(bytes32 _id) {
        registry.register(_id);
    }
    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id) {
        registry.getContractAddress(_id);
    }
    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id) {
        registry.getPublicAddress(_id);
    }
}
```

The `registry()`, `getPublicAddress()`, and `getContractAddress()` are not working and I can't understand why.

I tried testing with Truffle but ran into a known bug which is unsolved as of now. I asked about it [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24915/testing-contract-interactions-with-truffle), the discussion on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/84).

I tried running it in my private blockchain, where I have the following code

```
register: function(publicAddress, contractAddress, _id) {
    // Getting that user's instance of the contract
    const contract = contractInstance("User", contractAddress);
    // Interaction with the contract
    contract.register(web3.fromAscii(_id), {from: publicAddress}, (err, res) => {
        // Log transaction to explore
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('tx: ' + res);
            helpers.addTransaction(publicAddress, res);
        }
    });
},
getContractAddress: function(contractAddress, _id) {
    const contract = contractInstance("User", contractAddress);
    contract.getContractAddress.call(web3.fromAscii(_id), (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
},
getPublicAddress: function(contractAddress, _id) {
    const contract = contractInstance("User", contractAddress);
    contract.getPublicAddress.call(web3.fromAscii(_id), (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
}
```

After registering (and mining) I simply get back

```
[]
```

when calling `getPublicAddress()`or `getContractAddress()`.

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: Do you have to pass `bytes32` parameters `getPublicAddress` and `getContractAddress` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contract has many bugs, as follows:

- `reg` params, there is no way to set it. Default value of reg is zero, so Register contract wouldn't be called when you call `getPublicAddress` method.
- There is no return values of `getPublicAddress` and
  `getContractAddress` methods.

So i modified your contract and test everything is ok in [remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.13+commit.fb4cb1a.js), contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract Registry {

    mapping(bytes32 => address) public ID;
    mapping(address => address) public Contract;

    event log(bytes32,address);
    function register(bytes32 _id) {
        ID[_id] = tx.origin;
        Contract[tx.origin] = msg.sender;
    }

    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) {
        log(_id,ID[_id]);
        return (ID[_id]);
    }

    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) { 
        log(_id,Contract[ID[_id]]);
        return Contract[ID[_id]];
    } 
}

contract User { 
    address owner;
    Registry registry;
    // Register in the system
    function register(bytes32 _id) {
        registry.register(_id);
    }
    function getContractAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address){
        return registry.getContractAddress(_id);
    }
    function getPublicAddress(bytes32 _id) constant returns (address) {
        return registry.getPublicAddress(_id);
    }
    function setRegister(address _addr){
        registry = Registry(_addr);
    }
}
```

At first, you should deploy Register contract and then User contract, now copy Register contract address to call `setRegister` method, mined and test. The result is

[image]

Hope it helps~