# How to compile .sol file from the command-line?

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx, compilation

How do I compile a solidity file (e.g. [`05_greeter.sol`](https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/05_greeter.sol)) from the command-line into bytecode?

Without using IDE such as *Mix*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions are well documented [here](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/compiling_contract.html), the steps would be

1. Make sure solidity is recognised by your geth installation `eth.compile.solidity("")`
2. Let us take this simple contract source: `source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"`
3. Compile it `contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test`
4. [Deploy](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/creating_contract.html) it

#### Compile `.sol` files directly

See [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2609/259).
Or you can use tools like [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) to deploy it. In truffle you can create a contract and deploy it via commands.