# How TokenCreator/OwnedToken example from Solidity documentation works

Tags: solidity

In this post ([Understanding TokenCreator/OwnedToken example from Solidity documentation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/understanding-tokencreator-ownedtoken-example-from-solidity-documentation)) the detailed response was given, but I still have a question about "how it works".

```
contract OwnedToken {
    // TokenCreator is a contract type that is defined below.
    // It is fine to reference it as long as it is not used
    // to create a new contract.
    TokenCreator public creator;
    address public owner;
    string public name;

    // This is the constructor which registers the
    // creator and the assigned name.
    function OwnedToken(string _name) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        // We do an explicit type conversion from `address`
        // to `TokenCreator` and assume that the type of
        // the calling contract is TokenCreator, there is
        // no real way to check that.
        creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);
        name = _name;
    }

    function changeName(string newName) {
        // Only the creator can alter the name --
        // the comparison is possible since contracts
        // are implicitly convertible to addresses.
        if (msg.sender == address(creator))
            name = newName;
    }

    function transfer(address newOwner) {
        // Only the current owner can transfer the token.
        if (msg.sender != owner) 
            return;
        // We also want to ask the creator if the transfer
        // is fine. Note that this calls a function of the
        // contract defined below. If the call fails (e.g.
        // due to out-of-gas), the execution here stops
        // immediately.
        if (creator.isTokenTransferOK(owner, newOwner))
            owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract TokenCreator {

    mapping(string => address) addresses;

    function getAddress(string name) constant returns (address) {
        return addresses[name];
    }

    function createToken(string name)
       returns (OwnedToken tokenAddress)
    {
        // Create a new Token contract and return its address.
        // From the JavaScript side, the return type is simply
        // "address", as this is the closest type available in
        // the ABI.
        tokenAddress = new OwnedToken(name);
        addresses[name] = tokenAddress;
    }

    function changeName(string oldName, string newName) {
        // Again, the external type of "tokenAddress" is
        // simply "address".
        address tokenAddress = addresses[oldName];
        delete addresses[oldName];
        addresses[newName] = tokenAddress;
        OwnedToken(tokenAddress).changeName(newName);
    }

    function isTokenTransferOK(
        address currentOwner,
        address newOwner
    ) returns (bool ok) {
        // Check some arbitrary condition.
        address tokenAddress = msg.sender;
        return (sha3(newOwner) & 0xff) == (bytes20(tokenAddress) & 0xff);
    }
}
```

I didn't get when "function OwnedToken(string _name)" is called? As far as I understand When we call "new OwnedToken(name);" - "this does not execute a constructor" (c) as it's said in official documentation. As I assume it only creates an instance of "OwnedToken" contract and SOMEHOW (how it works, tho?) deploys it to SOME (where this address is located at?) address;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the latest [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new), any arguments passed while creating a contract via `new` will be passed in constructor

```
contract D {
    uint public x;
    constructor(uint a) payable {
        x = a;
    }
}
```

then,

```
D d = new D(4); // will be executed as part of C's constructor
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, now I see they've changed it. And new docs are way more clear for understanding!