# How to deploy compiled contract file using the geth cli?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, solc, compilation

So I've followed the *greeter* contract tutorial from here to deploy a contract to my private cloud. It works fine and all, but it is rather difficult that I need to create a string from my contract and then deploy that. It would be easier if I could create a `contract.sol` file and compile that.

So I put the greeter code into a file:

```
contract mortal {
    address owner;

    function mortal() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract greeter is mortal {
    string greeting;

    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns(string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

and ran the following command:

```
solc --optimize --bin contract.sol
```

This creates two new files:

```
greeter.bin
mortal.bin
```

But from here I'm kinda lost. Does anybody know how I can deploy this greeter contract using `geth` and these two bin files? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private)

Comment: @niksmac - The question you're linking to is not a duplicate. That deals with deploying from within the geth console by using the contract as a string. What I want to do is deploy a contract from a solidity source file.

Comment: I guess the only way to deploy smart contracts is to send bytecode to the blockchain through a transaction. You cannot deploy the source file. The code needs to be compiled and deterministic since it's being run in the EVM.

Comment: @kramer65 then this might help http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2609/259

Answer (score 1):

The geth Javascript console is more adapted to interactive use, when compiling directly with solc, RPC is usually a better choice. To deploy contracts see:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction

You can write a simple bash script to compose the json parameter and pass the right data in.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a read through it. I now understand how I can send ether using the RPC interface, but I'm unfamiliar with the command to deploy a contract. Would you possibly have an example of how to do that using the RPC interface?

Comment: May be this can help : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

Answer (score 0):

Try the [web3 CLI tool](https://github.com/gochain-io/web3), you can just run:

```
web3 contract deploy greeter.bin
```

That will deploy and return the contract address.

Can also build with: `web3 contract build greeter.sol`