# Smart Contract different behaviour on testnet vs Solidity Browser

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, testnets, remix

The following smart contract behaves differently on Solidity Browser and testnet:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.2;

contract mortal {
    address owner;

    function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

    function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }
}

contract myEscrow is mortal {
    uint numEscrows;

    function queryNumEscrows() constant returns (uint) {
        return numEscrows;
    }

    function start() returns (uint) {
        numEscrows++;

        return numEscrows;
    }

}
```

On [Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) it behaves as it should, increasing the value `numEscrows` when `start()` is called, and `queryNumEscrows()` returns this value correctly.

On testnet, the value `numEscrows` seems to be stuck on 0. `queryNumEscrows()` always returns 0, no matter how many times `start()` has been called.

On testnet I deployed in this way:

```
personal.unlockAccount("0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937", "pass", 86400);
personal.unlockAccount("0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d", "pass", 86400);
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937").toNumber(), "ether")
    "1673.35...."

var myescrowContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"queryNumEscrows","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"start","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var myescrow = myescrowContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: 4700000
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })


Contract mined! address: 0x95162fb5af8fae1970a90d891ca3862b020dda60 transactionHash: 0xfd5107184eba5cd2032759987ed7dace2de3328c2e8461b50b1d5a9a9e3ae12f
https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x95162fb5af8fae1970a90d891ca3862b020dda60

// This should be zero, right
myescrow.queryNumEscrows();
0


// Start escrow from Alice to Bob for 1 euro <=> 10^9 weis
myescrow.start.sendTransaction("0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b", "0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937", {from:"0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d", value:"0x3b9aca00"}, function (err, result) { if (err) { console.error(err); return; } else {console.log('txhash: ' + result)} });
0x445b6c9a7c735a54fd246596d40e2e8726244a91b98c512ca7ff9c1a5bd82c00


// After several minutes ...
myescrow.queryNumEscrows();
0
```

Why `numEscrows` is not increasing?

P.S.: By the way, I have deployed this very smart contract on testnet using **Mist** and it works, increasing `numEscrows` properly. But when deploying directly through geth console, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Work perfectly on testnet.

I'm using the `stripCrLf` script at [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2610/1268).

Here's your code, slightly tidied, saved into MyEscrow.sol :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.2;

contract Mortal {
    address owner;

    function Mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

    function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }
}

contract MyEscrow is Mortal {
    uint numEscrows;

    function queryNumEscrows() constant returns (uint) {
        return numEscrows;
    }

    function start() returns (uint) {
        numEscrows++;
        return numEscrows;
    }
}
```

I ran the following command to flatten your code:

```
user@Kumquat:~/ESE/Escrow$ echo "var myEscrowSource='`stripCrLf MyEscrow.sol`'"
var myEscrowSource='pragma solidity 0.4.2;contract Mortal { address owner; function Mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }}contract MyEscrow is Mortal { uint numEscrows; function queryNumEscrows() constant returns (uint) { return numEscrows; } function start() returns (uint) { numEscrows++; return numEscrows; }}'
```

I executed the following code in my `geth --cache=1024 --testnet console` command line:

```
> var myEscrowSource='pragma solidity 0.4.2;contract Mortal { address owner; function Mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }}contract MyEscrow is Mortal { uint numEscrows; function queryNumEscrows() constant returns (uint) { return numEscrows; } function start() returns (uint) { numEscrows++; return numEscrows; }}'
undefined
> var myEscrowCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(myEscrowSource);
undefined
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "MyVerySecretPasswordNumber1");
true
> var myEscrowContract = web3.eth.contract(myEscrowCompiled.MyEscrow.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> var myEscrow = myEscrowContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: myEscrowCompiled.MyEscrow.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
Contract mined! Address: 0x3fd50995536919085c28fdf9e07a03bad955cc33

myEscrow.start(eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: myEscrowCompiled.MyEscrow.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
"0x0b2ec2ee98b21214cca5be9294f3c019239d3d90f6e23c03a3eb7d6fcc8c1c29"
> myEscrow.queryNumEscrows()
1
```

Your code is working perfectly on testnet. Check your deployment statement, in particular your `myescrow.start.sendTransaction(...)` statement.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like we need to use `selfdestruct` now though. In place of `suicide`.